# Does any one know or can make an extension to open API URLs (especially, Whatsapp's) as a web URL?

Tags: url, whatsapp

Does any one know or can make an extension or JavaScript to automatically open API URLs (especially, Whatsapp's) as a web. url?
I want to open the API URLs in the browser, instead of the Whatsapp application.

I'm not a programmer. I have searched the web, but found no script or extension for that.